# Python can't find installed (user-site) application

Tags: python, pip

I've just installed [compiledb](https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb) , OS: RHEL6

```
pip install --user compiledb
```

running it from the command line doesn't work:

```
$ compiledb
```

tells me that no compiledb command found.

I also tried

```
python comppiledb
```

the error was something like compiledb is not a script.

probably I should manually add user site-packages directory to some (?) path? what is a right way?

I know that's newbie question, but I couldn't find similar problem by googling.
and - yes, I don't know python just need (`compildb`) to convert makefile to compilation database, not more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the second case first. Try adding the `-m` flag when you run it with `python`:

```
python -m compiledb
```

To get it running as `compiledb` you probably need to add the `pip` user binary directory to your `PATH`. Let's see where `pip install --user` puts libraries on your machine. Run this on the command line:

```
python -c 'import site; print(site.USER_BASE)'
```

On my system this prints

```
/home/chris/.local
```

and binaries installed via `pip install --user` live in

```
/home/chris/.local/bin
```

Assuming you get similar output, you should be able to run `compiledb` as

```
/home/amigo421/.local/bin/compiledb
```

If that works you may want to add `/home/amigo421/.local/bin` to your `PATH`, e.g. by adding something like

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/amigo421/.local/bin"
```

to your [`~/.bash_profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/12606) then logging out and back in again. At that point you should be able to simply run

```
compiledb
```

Comment: on first command: compiledb is a package and can't be directly executed

Comment: on second command - the same output (with my account name only)

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: yes, compiledb is a runnable there (in bin) subfolder, but is not successfully. invalid syntax in a code in __init__.py, line:70: orig={gen_key(c): c for (error here) c in compdb if "file" in c}

Comment: version is  2.6.6

Comment: That's pretty ancient, and `compiledb` says it's only tested on Python 2.7 and 3.6. Can you upgrade your Python? Both approaches work fine on my machine with Python 3.7, but even going to 2.7 will probably help.

Comment: I have no sudo there, could you clarify - is this possible to have a local installation of python ?

Comment: You could create a virtual environment. That's beyond the scope of SO, but there are plenty of tutorials and tools out there for doing that.

Comment: many thanks. I see VirtualEnv installed on my box and found the tutorials for that